# MySQL cannot be empty?

Tags: mysql

I was using the [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) "TEXT" data type for my post content. When I add an entry to the database, that coloumn cannot be blank. How can I force this? Could you help me?

Comment: How can you set *what*? That you *can* omit the column or that you *cannot* omit the column?

Comment: So you want the column to accept null values or not?

Comment: @NahuelIanni cannot be blank

Comment: Is the column set to NOT NULL? Can you show us your query?

Answer (score 0):

Make this TEXT column as `not null`

For modifying the existing column to not allow null use the below code

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name TEXT NOT NULL;
```

Comment: I couldnt set. Default---> As Defined ---> not null   I did this and it gave error

Comment: i have updated the answer. Try that to update the column

Comment: Isn't this the opposite?

Answer (score 0):

use this method

```
if ($_POST['var1'] == '') {
    $db_var1 = 'NULL';
} else {
    $db_var1 = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['var1']) . "'";
}
```